# How to correctly obtain synchronized audio/video timestamps for live streaming from iPhone/iOS

Tags: ios, core-audio

I am trying to stream live video+audio from an iPhone to the server.
What is the correct way to obtain timestamps?

In particular,

1. How to correctly produce an audio timestamp from 
   AudioTimeStamp->mSampleTime and AudioTimeStamp->mHostTime fields?
2. What is really the difference between mSampleTime and mHostTime fields? What's the meaning of those?
3. Should CMSampleBufferGetOutputPresentationTimeStamp() be used for obtaining video timeStamp?
4. Or should CVTimeStamp struct be used instead, but where (which method) can I obtain it from?
5. Any examples on the topic?

Needless to say, video and audio should be synchronized, I expect these timestamps to match.

Sorry for poorly asked question, wouldn't have asked if I knew better :)